# Get the the last ms before tomorrow in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime

I'm using the `Between` command in SQL Server.

I need to find :

```
 select * from MyTable where myDate
 between getdate() and [1ms before tomorrow  = 2012-02-26 :23:59:59:999]
```

*I DON'T want [ 2012-02-27 :00:00:00:000] because future queries should use that value .*

*So I need 1 ms before tomorrow.*

However  - this is what I've tried but for some reason it refuse to give me the desire value !
and give me :  `2012-02-26 23:59:59.997` + unpredictable results!

Why is that ? What am I missing ?

I want to get `2012-02-26 :23:59:59:999` !

[image]

Comment: Why do you *need* to use `BETWEEN`? As I commented below, an open-ended range is *much* more reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL Server `DATETIME` has an accuracy of 3.33ms - you'll **always** get the `.997` as the closest value to a full hour. That's just the way it is, and you cannot change it in SQL Server 2005. Read all about it at [Demystifying the SQL Server DATETIME datatype](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2004/datetime-datatype/).

In SQL Server 2008, you can use the `DATETIME2` datatype which has an accuracy of 100ns - so there you have up to 7 exact digits after the "seconds" decimal point.

**Update:** if you want to get .999 with a `DATETIME2`, you need to use:

```
DECLARE @dt2 DATETIME2
-- you need to cast GETDATE() to DATETIME2 - otherwise it's a DATETIME !
SET @dt2 = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME2) 

DECLARE @dt2_Added DATETIME2
SET @dt2_Added = DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, @dt2) + 1, 0) 

SELECT DATEADD(ms, -1, @dt2_added)
```

Result:

```
2012-02-26 23:59:59.9990000
```

**Update #2:** things get stranger still.....

If I use `SYSDATETIME()` instead of `GETDATE()`, it gives me a `DATETIME2` right from the get to - but if I do the calculation in one step:

```
DECLARE @dt2 DATETIME2
SET @dt2 = SYSDATETIME()

SELECT DATEADD(ms, -1, DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, @dt2) + 1, 0) )
```

I get the result of :

```
2012-02-27 00:00:00.000
```

but if I do the same calculation in two steps:

```
DECLARE @dt2 DATETIME2
SET @dt2 = SYSDATETIME()

DECLARE @dt2_Added DATETIME2
SET @dt2_Added = DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, @dt2) + 1, 0) 

SELECT DATEADD(ms, -1, @dt2_added)
```

I get the expected result:

```
2012-02-26 23:59:59.9990000
```

This is indeed quite weird......

Comment: can i build an object with the 99:999 value ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: **NOT** with the SQL Server 2005 `DATETIME` datatype

Comment: @RoyiNamir: of course that doesn't work..... `GETDATE` return a **`DATETIME`** - unless you explicitly cast it! See my update ....

Answer (score 3):

Why not specify an exclusive range instead?

```
SELECT * FROM `MyTable`
 WHERE `myDate` >= GETDATE() AND `myDate` < (tomorrow)
```

<sup>(I can't be bothered to figure out how to get tomorrow's `DATETIME` as I'm usually a MySQL guy, but I believe you already know how to do it.)</sup>

Otherwise you're stuck messing around with floating-point values of questionable accuracy.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes, I know. I'm suggesting that you do not, hence the use of the word "instead". `BETWEEN` implements an _inclusive range_, whereas you are trying to implement an _exclusive range_. Why not do that properly, instead of hacking around an inclusive range?

Comment: @Royi just because you *are* using `BETWEEN` doesn't mean you should. Guess what happens then the underlying data type gets changed to `SMALLDATETIME`? Please read these posts: https://sqlblog.org/dates ... I can't stress enough how unreliable and unintuitive `BETWEEN` can be.